# Distinguish devices from other network using UDP/DNS

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, dns, udp

I have got a LAN with two devices (+ router with PAT enabled). Both of them are communicating with external server using DNS (UDP packets). Is it possible for server to distingush these two devices (when I recieve DNS request I want to know which device is sender)?

### Network diagram

[image: Click here to see network diagram]

I tried to achieve that by simply checking sender ports of incoming packets, but they were completely random. I know that you can distinguish two deivces from other network using session layer, but probably it won't be possible with DNS.

Comment: How are you checking src ports? Are you running an application on the DNS server or what is the reasoning for distinguishing between the two clients?

Comment: Yup, there is an application on the DNS server listening on port 53. When DNS request arrives I simply check sender port of UDP packet. However, I cannot tell which client is actually sender, because his web browser can use multiple ports.

Comment: This is called an ephemeral port and the operating system chooses the src port, which means it is most likely different every time. Again, what is the purpose of what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need to distinguish between DNS requests?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with DNS. The DNS server will always see the source of the request as your router, and as you already observed, the source port is seemingly random (due to NAT.) Can you have the two clients query different and unique records?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, I cannot affect on client's requests. Will try to deal with it differently.